# Error invoking method, failed to launch jvm

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm developing a desktop application using javafx v8.0.40. I have created an exe file with inno 5. When I run exe file in my computer, it is installed and run without any problem. On the other hand, when I try to install and run it on some other computer, at the end of installation, window dialog pops up: "Error invoking method", I click Ok. Another window pop up saying "Failed to launch jvm". I searched the whole internet, but I couldn't find much about this topic. I hope I will get solution to this problem.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi! Your question lacks precision! Which Version of javafx, which version of inno, what does your code look like, and so on! Please have a look at the [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions on stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004035/javafx-application-fail-to-launch-with-native-exe-bundle, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212291/javafx-exe-file-failed-due-to-exception-in-main-class, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253079/failed-to-launch-javafx-application-with-native-bundle-exe. Take your pick. If neither of these questions provide a solution, they should give you an idea with what information you have to supplement your question.

Comment: @tarlan, don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it helped you (or others) with the problem at hand.

Answer (score 17):

I ran into the same problem; the following worked for me and helped me make sense of those blasted "Error invoking method." and "Failed to launch JVM" dialogs:

1. Find your `.jar` file

   - It has the same name as your Project and it's in your application's installation directory under `AppData\Local\{ApplicationTitle}\app` (*shortcut: type %appdata% into explorer*); if your project was named HelloWorld, there you will find `HelloWorld.jar`
2. Navigate to it's directory in command prompt

   - <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Click</kbd> any blank spot in the Explorer window and choose "Open command window here" *(that's a fancy trick I recently learned; [alternatively you would `cd`](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how+to+cd+in+command+prompt+for+noobs) to the same directory using the command prompt)*
3. Run your `.jar` via the command line

   - type `java -jar "HelloWorld.jar"` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Tadah!** Behold your hidden exceptions (the existence of which "Error invoking method." so vaguely tries to communicate to you). *

If your problem is similar to [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38108585/5432315) it stems from a file structure difference between the project `out` folder and the installation directory, and that's why the program compiles just fine in the editor and builds just fine—there isn't a problem until it's built out, and the file structure is a little different.

*If you didn't get anything when you ran it via the command line, look for any errors that could be happening during that `initialize()` method; that's where your problem likely is. **You can expose any exceptions during runtime by using a Popup Exception Dialog like shown in [a similar problem, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38108585/5432315).**

Comment: Had a similar problem but with a 3rd party application. This answer pointed me in the right direction. Looks like the code was not honouring the `%appdata%` variable. I reinstalled it into a directory with a fixed name, which would be the same in all language variants of Windows (`C:\Users\user` in my case), and the exception went away.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably because it lacks the dependencies in the output jar. So you need to add the libraries in the artifact and then .exe generation should be ok.

Here is an example with Intellij, where the libraries have be manually moved from "Available Elements" to the artifact

[Intellij example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScB6d.png)

Answer (score 4):

even though this question is a little old - today I faced the exact same problem and couldn't find any solution searching for those error messages other then here.

The problem is pretty much identically:
Built JavaFX Application (running fine on dev pc) using java 8 and packaged to native installer (exe) using Inno 5.
Application ran fine on some of our machines - on others it failed with exact those to error messages:

- "Error invoking method"
  and after clicking OK
- "Failed to launch jvm".

On application startup, the fxml loader loads the first view controller and calls its "initialize" method. If - within initialize - an unhandeled exception is being thrown, the application crashes and those two windows error messages are shown.

Hope that this will help some one who like me is struggling with that, too.

Answer (score 3):

The response by J.Dürr (answered Jun 8 '16 at 9:58) helped solve my *Error invoking method* & *Failed to launch JVM* issue. I used the following code to track down the issue, which turned out to be an errant FXML resource path:

```
public static void main(final String[] taArgs)
{
  try
  {
    Main.launch(taArgs);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    try
    {
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("<somefilename.txt>"));
      e.printStackTrace(pw);
      pw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e1)
    {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue and @Brad Turek's answer pointed me at the right direction. Except it wasn't my code that throw the exception.

The .cfg file (at `/<app_name>/app/<app_name>.cfg`) that the .exe wrapper used to start my application had incorrectly pointed to libs (jar files) that didn't exist at the `/lib` directory. Which (I concluded) caused the classloader to throw and terminate the startup.

After correcting the .cfg file everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I could not fix the problem, but I found a way around it. I used notepad to create a batch file to launch the app. First I used `cd` to get to the directory of the `.jar` file and then used `java -jar` to launch the app. It should look something like this:

```
cd C:\[wherever your project folder is located]\[name of project]\dist
java -jar [name of project].jar
```

Save it as a `.bat` file on the desktop, launch the batch file and your program will boot!

Answer (score 0):

You could experience this error if you didn't include the third-party libraries to the build.

The following can be placed in the build.xml just before the end tag of the project.

```
<target name="-post-jfx-deploy">
    <fx:deploy width="${javafx.run.width}" height="${javafx.run.height}" nativeBundles="all"
               outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" outfile="${application.title}">
        <fx:application name="${application.title}" mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"/>
        <fx:resources>
            <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>       
            <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="lib/*.jar"/>
        </fx:resources>
        <fx:info title="${application.title}" vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
    </fx:deploy>
```