# javafx native package error invoking method

Tags: ant, javafx-2, netbeans-8

I'm developing a desktop application using javafx v8.0.60. I have created an exe package with ant in netbeans 8. When I run exe file in my computer, it is installed and run without any problem.

On the other hand, when I try to install and run it on some other computer, at the end of installation, window dialog pops up:

> "Error invoking method"

I click Ok. Another window pop up saying:

> "Failed to launch jvm"

Comment: This problem is already discussed in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285108/error-invoking-method-failed-to-launch-jvm/35179193#35179193

Answer (score 1):

Davood, greetings! I had this same problem and I, like you, found no help anywhere.

I submit to you a solution, which miraculously worked for me and helped me make sense of those blasted "Error invoking method." and "Failed to launch JVM" dialogs:

1. Find your `.jar` file

   - It has the same name as your Project and it's in your application's installation directory under `AppData\Local\{ApplicationTitle}\app` (*shortcut: type %appdata% into explorer*); if your project was named HelloWorld, there you will find `HelloWorld.jar`
2. Navigate to it's directory in command prompt

   - <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Click</kbd> any blank spot in the Explorer window and choose "Open command window here" *(that's a fancy trick I recently learned; [alternatively you would `cd`](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how+to+cd+in+command+prompt+for+noobs) to the same directory using the command prompt)*
3. Run your `.jar` via the command line

   - type `java -jar "HelloWorld.jar"` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Tadah!** Behold your hidden exceptions (the existence of which "Error invoking method." so vaguely tries to communicate to you). *

If your problem is similar to [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38108585/5432315) it stems from a file structure difference between the project `out` folder and the installation directory, and that's why the program compiles just fine in the editor and builds just fine—there isn't a problem until it's built out, and the file structure is a little different.

*If you didn't get anything when you ran it via the command line, look for any errors that could be happening during that `initialize()` method; that's where your problem likely is. **You can expose any exceptions during runtime by using a Popup Exception Dialog like shown in [a similar problem, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38108585/5432315).**