# AWS Schema Conversion Tool not launching

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sct

I've installed AWS SCT following the steps in the documentation. When I try to launch it, it throws an error [Launch Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHAHt.png). Any idea why this is happening or how to fix this?

The installation is on an EC2 instance running Windows 10 with the latest version of JVM.

Comment: Try troubleshooting as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38001576/error-invoking-method-and-failed-to-launch-jvm-native-package-will-build-but/38108585#38108585