# JavaFx Self-Contained application on Windows requires administrator privileges

Tags: java, javafx, jvm, javafx-8

I developed a JavaFx self-contained application for Windows. I created both .exe and .msi packages.
I need that the application is installed for machine, not for user. The installation goes fine, but when I try to run the application from user limited account, the application doesn't start and give the error "Class it/xxx/xxx/Main not found" and then "Failed to lauch JVM".

Running the application with administrative privileges instead it works fine.

There is a way to solve this very annoying issue? In Windows enviroments (domain controller) usually users have not administrative privileges and it's very restrictive ask the customer to open it only to make the JavaFx application works.

I hope there is a way to solve it.

Comment: One of these comments may be helpful.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285108/error-invoking-method-failed-to-launch-jvm

Comment: I face the same problem when i build `JavaFX applications` and deploy them,although i have not found a solution for that :(

Comment: Are you using the bundled JRE or are you depending on the system-installed JRE? Which JDK was used for bundling?

Comment: I'm using the bundled JRE. I'm usign JDK 1.8u112

Comment: Thanks to @SedrickJefferson I solved the problem. I found useful run the application with system jdk via console. So I figured out that was an Exception because log4j was not able to write logs in C:\Programs Files\myApp because the user had not privileges to do that. So I change log4j configuration and now all works fine. Thanks!