# error after build javafx exe with intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, build, exe, artifacts

[step 1:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5dOy.jpg)

[step 2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1wXB.jpg)

[step 3:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Or02a.jpg)

[erroe after run exe file :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nq081.jpg)

[and second error :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7vDn.jpg)

Please help me, thanks

Comment: Can you run the jar file? Typically you should test that first and see if you get any exceptions.

Comment: checkout this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285108/error-invoking-method-failed-to-launch-jvm

Comment: i tested the jar file but after run jar file, no program is execute

Comment: Run it from the command line and post any stack trace in the question. (I assume this runs fine directly in the IDE.)

Comment: i find my problem!
i use jfoenix.jar library, and when delete JFXButton and... project is run!
but i want use jfoenix lib. what should i do?