# Unirest in a runnable javafx application

Tags: java, javafx, jar, javafx-8, unirest

I have the following problem. I wrote a java application using javafx and unirest for the internet access. When I run the app in my ide (intellij), everything works fine. But when I generate an exe nothing happens. I did some investigation and found this ([Error invoking method, failed to launch jvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285108/error-invoking-method-failed-to-launch-jvm)). When I completely deactivate the unirest code the app starts, but without function of course. It's then first time for me to create a runnable version of java code and code overall. I use a single call from the unirest lib:

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse
                    = Unirest.get("website")
                    .header("key", "value")
                    .asJson();
```

Like I said everything works great without a single error in the ide. May Windows blocks the internet for the exe and that results in an exception. I whitelisted the files both in my antivirus and my firewall, but it didn't helped. I have no idea how I can go on from this point. Would be nice if someone could help me.

In reference to Slaw's comment. When you quickly want to reproduce the problem, create a new javafx project, add a button and a textArea to the fxml file, add the unirest lib and then the following code to the "Controller.java":

```
 @FXML
Button button;

@FXML
TextArea text;

public void initialize(){

    button.setOnAction((event -> {

        try {
            HttpResponse<String> jsonResponse
                    = Unirest.get("https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/pc/bob")
                    .asString();
            text.setText(jsonResponse.getBody().toString());
        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }));
}
```

Run the application in the ide, it starts without problem, when you click the button "{"message":"No API key found in request"}" is printed in the textArea like expected. When you build a runnable version and then try to start it, in case one nothing happens or in case two two popups show up with "Error invoking method" and "Failed to launch JVM".

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue; include the error you're getting.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I followed your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem and its completely my fault. Cause I am new to this I followed 2 tutorials on YouTube to create the executable. It seems that I have to add the unirest lib separately to the "JavaFXApp" artifact.
It can be found by following File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Artifacts -> select the artifact -> under "Output Layout" press the "+" button and add all the lib's you use in your project like you have add them to the project itself.

Nevertheless thank you for the quick answer Slaw.